# Declaration difference in Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".s"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("as");  
boolean b = m.matches();
```

> And:

```
boolean b3 = Pattern.matches(".s", "as");
```

I want to know what is the difference between these two declaration?

`> mathches()` is Matcher class method how can Pattern call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matches()` is the `static` method in `Pattern` class which calls `matches()` method in `Matcher`. Here's the source [code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
public static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        return m.matches();
    }
```

Comment: there are two matches() method right?

Comment: Two? one method in `Pattern` that calls one in `Matcher`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the implementation of `Pattern.matches`:

```
public static boolean matches(String var0, CharSequence var1) {
    Pattern var2 = compile(var0);
    Matcher var3 = var2.matcher(var1);
    return var3.matches();
}
```

and you see that the latter is just a convenience method for the more verbose first snippet.